# Python file not getting the values from html file in django for login page

Tags: python, django

I have made a small login page but I am not able to get the user input values in the textbox to the python (i.e. `views.py`). Can anyone tell me why?

This is my URL's page

```py
from . import views
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.login),
    path('user_login/',views.studlogin,name='user_login/'),
]
```

This is the `views.py` file - `studlogin` function

```py
def studlogin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('Username')
        password = request.POST.get('Password')
        if username == "jake":
            return render(request, 'new.html')
```

The HTML code for the login page that is `index.html` is

```html
{% load static %}
     
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class=''>
<head>
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src='https://production-assets.codepen.io/assets/editor/live/console_runner-079c09a0e3b9ff743e39ee2d5637b9216b3545af0de366d4b9aad9dc87e26bfd.js'></script><script src='//production-assets.codepen.io/assets/editor/live/events_runner-73716630c22bbc8cff4bd0f07b135f00a0bdc5d14629260c3ec49e5606f98fdd.js'></script><script src='//production-assets.codepen.io/assets/editor/live/css_live_reload_init-2c0dc5167d60a5af3ee189d570b1835129687ea2a61bee3513dee3a50c115a77.js'></script><meta charset='UTF-8'><meta name="robots" content="noindex"><link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="//production-assets.codepen.io/assets/favicon/favicon-8ea04875e70c4b0bb41da869e81236e54394d63638a1ef12fa558a4a835f1164.ico" /><link rel="mask-icon" type="" href="//production-assets.codepen.io/assets/favicon/logo-pin-f2d2b6d2c61838f7e76325261b7195c27224080bc099486ddd6dccb469b8e8e6.svg" color="#111" /><link rel="canonical" href="https://codepen.io/aperyon/pen/oxzpaE?depth=everything&order=popularity&page=23&q=translate&show_forks=false" />
     
    <style class="cp-pen-styles">
        html, body {
            border: 0;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
        body {
            background: tomato;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        form {
            background: white;
            width: 40%;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            font-family: lato;
            position: relative;
            color: #333;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }
        form header {
            background: #FF3838;
            padding: 30px 20px;
            color: white;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            font-weight: 600;
            border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
        }
        form label {
            margin-left: 20px;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-top: 30px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            position: relative;
        }
        form label span {
            color: #FF3838;
            font-size: 2em;
            position: absolute;
            left: 2.3em;
            top: -10px;
        }
        form input {
            display: block;
            width: 78%;
            margin-left: 20px;
            padding: 5px 20px;
            font-size: 1em;
            border-radius: 3px;
            outline: none;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
        form .help {
            margin-left: 20px;
            font-size: 0.8em;
            color: #777;
        }
        form button {
            position: relative;
            margin-top: 30px;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, 0);
            font-family: inherit;
            color: white;
            background: #FF3838;
            outline: none;
            border: none;
            padding: 5px 15px;
            font-size: 1.3em;
            font-weight: 400;
            border-radius: 3px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.4);
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
        }
        form button:hover {
            background: #ff5252;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'user_login/' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}  
     
        <header>Login</header>
        <label>Username <span>*</span></label>
        <input type="text"   id="username" placeholder="Username" required="" />
        <div class="help">At least 5 character</div>
        <label>Password <span>*</span></label>
        <input type="password"  id="password" placeholder="Password" required="" />
        <div class="help">Use upper and lowercase letters as well</div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: This is the login page]

Why is it that I am not able to get the user input in the text box in the `views.py`?

Comment: Set the name attribute of your form fields in your template. Not only the id's.

Answer (score 0):

As Marco said, you need to set the name of your input

```
...
<input type="text" name="Username" id="username" placeholder="Username" required="" />
<label>Password <span>*</span></label>
<input type="password" name="Password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required="" />
...
```

You could also use django's embedded authentication system, or django form system (it generates the form for you so this kind of mistake never happens)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/